# Помогите, чего данные не записываются в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование, laravel

есть api. которое обрабатывает запрос и записывает в бд.

public function setbyRoomId(Request $request, $task_id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

```
    $leader = $user->getLeader();

    try
    {
        $task = Task::findOrFail($task_id);
    }catch (ModelNotFoundException $e){
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Bad request, task notfound',
            'payload' => [
            ]
        ], 400);
    }

    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), TRUE);
     $room = RoomNumber::where('room_number', $task->room_id)
        ->leftJoin('rooms_type', 'room_number.room_id', '=', 'rooms_type.id')
        ->where('rooms_type.leader_id', $leader->id)
        ->first(['room_number.room_id', 'room_number.room_number', 'rooms_type.name', 'rooms_type.description', 'rooms_type.minibar_id']);
    if (!$room){
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Bad request. Error in room number '.$task->room_id.' in task No '.$task->id ,
            'payload' => [
            ]
        ], 400);
    }
    $minibar = MinibarRoomType::where('minibar_room_type.room_id', $room->room_id)
        ->leftJoin('minibars', 'minibar_room_type.minibar_id', '=', 'minibars.id')
        ->where('minibars.leader_id', $leader->id)
        ->where('deleted_at', null)
        ->first(['minibar_room_type.minibar_id', 'minibars.name', 'minibars.description']);
    $goods = GoodsMinibar::where('minibar_id', $minibar->minibar_id)
        ->leftJoin('goods', 'goods_minibar.goods_id', '=', 'goods.id')
        ->where('goods.leader_id', $leader->id)
        ->get();
    $i=0;

    foreach ($goods as $item){
        foreach ($data['goods'] as $good){
            if (($item['goods_id'] == $good['id'])AND($item['quantity'] != $good['quantity'])) {
                $result[$i]['id']= $item['goods_id'];
                $result[$i]['name']= $item['name'];
                $result[$i]['balance']= $good['quantity'];
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

    $rrrr = $task->update(['executor_comment'=>$result]);

    return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => '',
        'payload' => [
            'result' => $result,
        ]
    ], 200);
}
```

положительный ответ отправляет но в базу не пишет.

Comment: что возвращает в `payload.result` ?

Comment: @VladChyorny {"success":true,"message":"","payload":{"result":[{"id":"1","name":"\u041f\u0435\u043f\u0441\u0438","balance":"0"}]}}

Comment: что вы пытаетесь сделать этой строчкой? `$rrrr = $task->update(['executor_comment'=>$result]);`

Comment: @VladChyorny обновить поле "executor_comment" в бд

Comment: @VladChyorny есть данные, которые можно изменить, те что изменились я хочу записать в ячейку "executor_comment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изминения объекта в Laravel делается по другому (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#updates):

```
$task->executor_comment = $result;
$task->save();
```

Comment: отлично спасибо! 
заработало вот так. 

$task->executor_comment = json_encode($result);
        $task->save();
только русские слова записались след. образом
\u041f\u0435\u043f\u0441\u0438
как сделать чтоб в нормальной кодировке отображались?

Comment: Вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498286/why-does-the-php-json-encode-function-convert-utf-8-strings-to-hexadecimal-entit

Comment: @olezha если работаете с json то с [этим будет удобней.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting)